# Prevent movement of folders

Tags: permissions

I have given access to a user to write files in specific folders. Now one of the user accidentally put one folder into the other while writing files, and the whole process took an hour to figure out what happened.

I want users to have write permissions, but they are not able to move one folder into another.

Comment: @guiverc mind if I remove the tag? :=D Me likes the question and it is universal applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Place a sticky bit on the parent folder and set the child directories to "root". The sticky bit will make it "only append".

```
sudo chmod +t ../
sudo chown root: {directory}/
```

Only root can do more than append to those directories.

Do this on a partition dedicated to this. Not in `/home/`; messing with permission on `/home/` is asking for problems: 1 mistake and you can not log in anymore.

Comment: Suppose all the directories are in /home. I have a two user1 and user2, so the directory structure becomes /home/user1 and /home/user2, now If i want to apply sticky bit, should I apply it to /home Only, so that user1 and user2 can't move directories(folders) into one another. Just need calirification. TIA

Comment: Nope. You do not use /home for this, you do this on a mount (ie. a user partition). BTW /home is already set to limit users to their own home.

Comment: Yes, the users are limited to their own home directory, and i want the same user within their home directory, restricted to move folders into one another